# A drain gradually gets clogged...

Tags: calculus

Been staring at this for a while. Having trouble getting started. It seems simple enough but it's kicking my ass. I'm sure I'm missing a simple method.

> In an experiment water pours through the drain that gets gradually clogged. In the first hour 1 gallon of water flowed through, and in every subsequent hour the amount of water pouring through the drain is equal to 2/3 of the amount that flowed through in the previous hour.
>
> a) How much water poured through the drain in the second hour? What is the total amount of water that flowed through the drain in the first 2 hours?
>
> b) How much water pours through the drain in the first 10 hours?
>
> c) How much water would flow through the drain if the experiment continued indefinitely?

Comment: What's keeping you from answering (a)? You don't eve have to compute anthying (ok, you have to perform *one* addition) for that...

Comment: You're right, but seeing as (b) is an extension of (a), I want to understand how to solve it using whatever method (exponential differential equation?) that is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will actually tackle this question with discrete math/sequences rather than calculus. Let $x_k$ denote the amount of water drained in the $k^\textrm{th}$ hour. Since the amount that flows through the drain is $\frac{2}{3}$ the previous hour, {$x_k$} forms a geometric progression.

Q(b) can be solved by using the formula for the sum of a geometric series $\displaystyle \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ where $a$ is the first term, $r$ the common ratio and $n$ the number of terms. Q(c) is then the sum to infinity.

We can probably approach it through setting up differential equations too but unless I'm overlooking something the discrete version will work the same and is definitely simpler.

Comment: Thanks. This is the kind of thing I was looking for. I'd been looking in the wrong direction!

Comment: You *are* using calculus! How do you think the formula for summing the infinite series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n^i$ is derived, if not with calculus?